# Oracle insert with check option

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

This is from the [Oracle Database 12 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm) for the insert statement:

> **WITH CHECK OPTION**
>
> Specify WITH CHECK OPTION to indicate that Oracle Database prohibits
>   any changes to the table or view that would produce rows that are not
>   included in the subquery. When used in the subquery of a DML
>   statement, you can specify this clause in a subquery in the FROM
>   clause but not in subquery in the WHERE clause.

I can't make sense of the last sentence:

> When used in the subquery of a DML statement, you can specify this
>   clause in a subquery in the FROM clause but not in subquery in the
>   WHERE clause.

It seems to imply that the WITH CHECK OPTION should come directly after the FROM clause, when the insert has a subquery. But it doesn't work. Quite the opposite.

When the WITH CHECK OPTION is placed after the WHERE clause it works correctly and produces the expected ORA-01402 error.

But when placed directly after the FROM clause it produces an "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error instead. I.e. putting the WITH CHECK OPTION after the FROM clause, as the documentation says, isn't valid SQL.

```
SQL> create table t1
  2  (
  3    col1 number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into
  2  (
  3    select * from t1
  4    where col1 = 1
  5    with check option
  6  )
  7  values (2);
  select * from t1
                *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation


SQL> insert into
  2  (
  3    select * from t1
  4    with check option
  5    where col1 = 1
  6  )
  7  values (2);
  where col1 = 1
  *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe "*not in subquery in the WHERE clause*" refers to something like `where id in (select ... with check option ..)`

Comment: Possibly. It just feels like the inner select would be called a subquery, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: I would call the inner select a "derived table", not a subquery

Comment: The inner `SELECT` is a subquery, but ISTM that there is restriction in using such subqueries in a `WHERE` clause - it's not specifying where the `WITH CHECK OPTION` should come when it is part of the subquery. The `CREATE VIEW` syntax indicates that `WITH CHECK OPTION` comes after the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think "WITH CHECK OPTION" is designed for VIEWS, but can be used in an INSERT subquery acting like a VIEW.

**To go with your example:**

```
SQL> create table t1
  2  (
  3    col1 number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create table t2
  2  (
  3    col1 number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1);

1 row inserted.

SQL> INSERT INTO t1
2 SELECT col1 
3 FROM ( SELECT col1 FROM t2 WHERE col1 = 1 WITH CHECK OPTION );

1 row inserted.
```

I suppose this is a subquery disguised as a view.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today - when reading the ref again, now it makes sense:
Considered we have:

```
INSERT into t1 
    Select c from ( 
        select c2 from t2 where c2=1 with check option
    )
```

- the check option is used inside the subselect (c2 from t2)
- ref says:

  > use in the from clause (of `select c from`) and not in the where clause - which is not existent here (but only in the subselect (of the subselect)

Answer (score 0):

WITH CHECK OPTION is mainly used with views.
For example, take two views here:

```
create view view_1 as select * from table_1 where table1_col1;
```

-- here view_1 can be altered by inserting or updating the rows

```
create view view_2 as select * from table_2 where table2_col1 with check option;
```

--here view_2 cannot be altered as it is created with check option.